# Get value in each line Java

Tags: java, string

I have a String, in each line there is a value with tag, how can I extract it?

My string : -

```
abi: armeabi-v7a
processor   : 0
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 14.47
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4
```

Like this I have many, I want to get each value from each tag, like `CPU part` tag I need to get `0xd03`. How can I do that?

Comment: Split the string per line. Then split on `:` (limit `2`). Then `trim()` the values. Collect into a `Map<String, String>`, done. Then you can just easily access everything like `map.get("CPU part")` and it gives you `"0xd03"`.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to, for example, print out all tags, you could try splitting the string on CR?LF, then using split again to isolate the value on the RHS of each line.

```
String input = "abi: armeabi-v7a\n" +
               "processor   : 0\n" +
               "Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)";
String[] lines = input.split("\r?\n");
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] parts = line.split("\\s*:\\s");
    System.out.println("key=" + parts[0] + ", value=" + parts[1]);
}
```

This prints, for the 3 line input given above:

```
key=abi, value=armeabi-v7a
key=processor, value=0
key=Processor, value=ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
```

Comment: `line.split("\\s*:\\s");` - why not just split on `:` ?

Comment: There is whitespace possibly on either side of the colon, which is not actually part of the key or value.

Comment: Oh I see.  Well thought of.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple algorithm.

1. Split the string by \n => splitString
2. Split splitString by :  => keyValues
3. Put the first part and second part of keyValues as keys and values of a HashMap for ease of access, or you could simply print the values.